# Как импортировать модуль выше по уровню, чем запускаемый файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Мне нужно запустить встроеный сервер Flask вот с такой структурой:

```
project
-project_name
--module1
--module2
--module3
---scripts
----my_scrit.py
```

Точка входа находится в файле `myscript.py`. В нем также есть импорты вот такого вида:

```py
from project_name.module1 import something
```

При попытке запустить файл `myscript.py` происходит ошибка, т.к. модуль `project_name` не найден. Что логично, т.к. это попытка импорта из каталогов выше главного файла.

Поэтому я ппробовал добавить в `PYTHONPATH` папку верхнего уровня, то есть `project`. Для этого в файле `activate` виртуального окружения я добавил вот такие строчки:

```
PYTHONPATH="/path/to/dir/project/"
export PYTHONPATH
```

Если в терминале написать `echo $PYTHONPATH`, то выводится этот путь. Но модуль `project_name` все равно не удается найти при запуске файла `myscript.py`. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй в файле скрипта до импорта добавить строки

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/dir/project/")
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает, но можно ли все-таки сделать это именно в настройках окружения?

Comment: А то, что в исходном вопросе фигурируют PYTHON_PATH и PYTHONPATH - это опечатка в вопросе или в самом скрипте?

Comment: это опечатка в вопросе)

Comment: а может кстати и не в вопросе. Вроде как заработало. Я окружение заново создал, поэтому проверить не могу)